# ASP.NET Web API DELETE method error

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Using the ASP.NET Web API DELETE method with entity framework to pass the student id and if the id exists in the table delete the record. When I try to test it I get the following error message

*"System.Data.Entity.Utilities.Check.NotNull[T](T value, String parameterName) System.Data.Entity.DbContext.Entry[TEntity](TEntity entity)"*

```
public class StudentController : ApiController
{
    [HttpDelete]
    [Route("student/DeleteStudent/{id}")]

    public IHttpActionResult DeleteStudent(string id)
    {
        using (var sd = new SchoolDBEntities())
        {
            var student = sd.Students
                .Where(s => s.StudentID == id)
                .FirstOrDefault();

            sd.Entry(student).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Deleted;
            sd.SaveChanges();
        }
        if (id == null)
        return BadRequest("Not a valid student id");

        return Ok();
    }
}
```

Comment: check my answer if (id == null) need to be done before you are doing delete operation...

Comment: please do accept/upvote answer it works for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check that student exists;

```
        var student = sd.Students
            .Where(s => s.StudentID == id)
            .FirstOrDefault();
        if (student != null)
        {
            sd.Entry(student).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Deleted;
            sd.SaveChanges();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Another thing is method should be fast fail so in you case, so check for null id comes first that can also be resole your issue, check this code:

```
public IHttpActionResult DeleteStudent(string id)
{
    if (id == null)
        return BadRequest("Not a valid student id");

    var student = sd.Students
                    .Where(s => s.StudentID == id)
                    .SingleOrDeault();

    if (student != null)
    {
        // perform operation
    }    

    return Ok();
}
```

As you are expecting only one student going to have `ID` which is the primary key and is an incremental number, then you should use `SingleOrDeault()`, do not use `FirstOrDefault()` as there cannot be more student with same id

```
var student = sd.Students
                .Where(s => s.StudentID == id)
                .SingleOrDeault();

if (student != null)
{
    // perform operation
}
```